# Tela de login no Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, login, logcat

Emulei um servidor local pelo XAMPP e comecei a tentar desenvolver um tela de login para um aplicativo Android.

Ele está funcionando perfeitamente, mas apenas quando faço login pelo `localhost`(utilizando meu endereço de IP local no lugar do localhost, pois a AVD faz o acesso como se o servidor fosse online) e entrando com o login e senha já pré-definidos. Quero fazer com que o login seja validado ao acessar a seguinte pagina: http://siga.ufvjm.edu.br/.

Eu consigo fazer isso funcionar modificando apenas parte do código abaixo? O fato de o sistema ser feito utilizando o Framework MIOLO afeta em algo?

```
btAcessar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.i("Logar", "Entrou no evento");
        String urlPost="http://localhost/android/logar.php";
        String urlGet="http://localhost/android/logar.php?usuario="+etUsuario.getText().toString()+"&senha="+etSenha.getText().toString();
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> parametrosPost = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        parametrosPost.add(new BasicNameValuePair("usuario", etUsuario.getText().toString()));
        parametrosPost.add(new BasicNameValuePair("senha", etSenha.getText().toString()));
        String respostaRetornada = null;
        Log.i("Logar", "Vai entrar no try");

        try{
            respostaRetornada = ConexaoHttpClient.executaHttpPost(urlPost, parametrosPost);
            //respostaRetornada = ConexaoHttpClient.executaHttpGet(urlGet);
            String resposta = respostaRetornada.toString();
            Log.i("Logar", "resposta = "+resposta);
            resposta = resposta.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
            if(resposta.equals("1"))
                startActivity(new Intent(Logar.this, MenuPrincipal.class));
                //mensagemExibir("Login", "Usuário Válido.");
            else
                mensagemExibir("Login", "Usuário Iválido.");
        }
        catch(Exception erro){
            Log.i("Erro", "erro = "+erro);
            Toast.makeText(Logar.this, "Erro.: "+erro, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    }
});
```

Quais mudanças serão necessárias para eu poder ir adiante?

Relatório do LogCat de quando substituo o localhost pelo endereço http://siga.ufvjm.edu.br/index.php?module=common&action=main:

```
10-09 12:54:09.709: I/Logar(930): Entrou no evento
10-09 12:54:09.709: I/Logar(930): Vai entrar no try
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): resposta = <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <html>
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <head>
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1" />
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <title>SIGA :: UFVJM</title>
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://siga.ufvjm.edu.br/images/icon_siga.gif" />
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://siga.ufvjm.edu.br/index.php?module=miolo&amp;action=themes:system:m_themeelement.css">
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://siga.ufvjm.edu.br/index.php?module=miolo&amp;action=themes:system:m_controls.css">
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://siga.ufvjm.edu.br/index.php?module=miolo&amp;action=themes:system:m_forms.css">
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://siga.ufvjm.edu.br/index.php?module=miolo&amp;action=themes:system:m_common.css">
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://siga.ufvjm.edu.br/index.php?module=miolo&amp;action=themes:system:m_boxes.css">
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://siga.ufvjm.edu.br/index.php?module=miolo&amp;action=themes:system:forms.css">
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://siga.ufvjm.edu.br/index.php?module=miolo&amp;action=themes:system:tabelas.css">
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://siga.ufvjm.edu.br/index.php?module=miolo&amp;action=themes:system:siga.css">
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <meta name="Generator" content="MIOLO Version Miolo 2.0 beta1; http://www.miolo.org.br">
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <script type="text/javascript" src="http://siga.ufvjm.edu.br/scripts/prototype/prototype.js"></script>
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <script type="text/javascript" src="http://siga.ufvjm.edu.br/scripts/m_miolo.js"></script>
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <script type="text/javascript" src="http://siga.ufvjm.edu.br/scripts/m_compatibility.js"></script>
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <script type="text/javascript" src="http://siga.ufvjm.edu.br/scripts/m_form.js"></script>
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <script type="text/javascript">
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): miolo.onSubmit = function ()
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): {
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930):     this.submit();
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930):     return true;
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): }
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): window.onload = function () {
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): MIOLO_GetElementById('uid').focus();
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930):    miolo.setTitle('SIGA :: UFVJM');
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): miolo.setForm('frm543685723f9db');
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): form_frm5436857246321 = new Miolo.form('frm5436857246321');
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): }
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): //-->
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): </script>
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): </head>
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <body class="m-theme-body">
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <form id="frm543685723f9db" name="frm543685723f9db" method="post" action="http://siga.ufvjm.edu.br/index.php?module=common&amp;action=main"  onSubmit="return miolo.onSubmit();" > 
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <div id="m-container">
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <div id="m-container-top">
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <div class="m-box-title"><span class="icon">
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <img src="http://siga.ufvjm.edu.br/index.php?module=miolo&amp;action=themes:system:images:icon_siga.gif" alt="" border="0"></span><span class="caption">&nbsp;SIGA&nbsp;-&nbsp;Sistema&nbsp;Integrado&nbsp;de&nbsp;Gest?o&nbsp;Acad?mica&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></div></div>
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <div id="m-container-module">
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <div id="m_m4" class="m-module-header"></div></div>
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <div id="m-container-content-full">
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <div style="float:left;margin-right:5px">
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <img src="http://siga.ufvjm.edu.br/index.php?module=miolo&amp;action=themes:system:images:logo_siga.jpg" alt="Home" border="0"></div>
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <div style="width:650px;float:left;margin-right:5px">
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <div id="frm5436857246321" class="m-form-box">
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <div id="m10" class="m-box-outer m-form-outer">
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <div class="m-box-box">
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <div class="m-box-title"><span class="icon">
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <img src="http://siga.ufvjm.edu.br/index.php?module=common&amp;action=html:images:lock.png" alt="" border="0"></span><span class="caption">Acesso&nbsp;ao&nbsp;Sistema&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></div>
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <div class="m-form-body">
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <div>
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <div class="m-form-row"><span class="label" style="width:25%">
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <label  class="m-caption" for="uid">Usu&aacute;rio:</label></span><span class="field" style="width:70%">
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <input  type="text" id="uid" class="m-text-field" name="uid" value="" size="20"></span></div>
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <div class="m-form-row"><span class="label" style="width:25%">
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <label  class="m-caption" for="pwd">Senha:</label></span><span class="field" style="width:70%">
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <input  typ
10-09 12:54:10.099: D/dalvikvm(930): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 236K, 13% free 2723K/3104K, paused 25ms, total 28ms
10-09 12:54:10.319: I/Choreographer(930): Skipped 54 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: Você precisa explicar melhor o que precisa, mas pelo pouco que entendi, você quer fazer logon em um site, certo ? Se sim, para começar, a url que você deve tentar fazer um post é http://siga.ufvjm.edu.br/index.php?module=common&action=main e os parâmetros são uid (login) e pwd (senha).

Comment: É exatamente isso que pretendo fazer. Já tentei adicionar essas informações no código, tanto o link quanto os parâmetros, mas ainda não obtive sucesso com apenas esses dados.

Comment: É interessante que você adicione na pergunta a resposta do servidor.

Comment: @Marpd144, está gerenciando os `Cookies`? Em geral o sistema deve manter uma sessão do usuário com `Cookies`.

Comment: @Luídne, farei isso. Obrigado.
Posso estar dando mancada em perguntar isso, mas o fato de o sistema da universidade ser feito utilizando o Framework MIOLO afeta em algo?

Comment: @Wakim, não estou, não cheguei a estudar essa parte ainda. Ela seria essencial para o funcionamento? Obrigado

Comment: @Marpd114, sim é primordial gerenciar o envio e recebimento de cookies. Senão é possível que sempre receba alguma mensagem de sessão expirada ou sem permissão.

Comment: @Wakim, irei dar uma estudada nessa parte tbm. Obrigado

Comment: Primeiro detalhe IMPORTATE!, 

`10-09 12:54:10.319: I/Choreographer(930): Skipped 54 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.` Utilize treads para fazer trabalho presados na aplicaçao. [de uma lida aqui.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 2):

Utilize Threads para fazer trabalhos pesados em sua aplicação, como acesso ao disco, downloads, processamento de imagens etc... [leia mais.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) Se você travar a thread principal do processo, a aplicação ira receber um [ANR](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html). ou seja você não pode travar a main thread por mais que 5 segundos e em caso de BroadsCast, não mais que 10 segundos.

```
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <label  class="m-caption" for="pwd">Senha:</label></span><span class="field" style="width:70%">
10-09 12:54:09.969: I/logar(930): <input  typ
10-09 12:54:10.099: D/dalvikvm(930): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 236K, 13% free 2723K/3104K, paused 25ms, total 28ms
10-09 12:54:10.319: I/Choreographer(930): Skipped 54 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

A resposta do servidor esta vindo incompleta, provavelmente por que o processo foi interrompido por travar por muito tempo a main thread, como você disse, usando servidor local funciona perfeitamente isos por que usando rede local ( sua maquina ) o tempo de resposta é rápido o suficiente para não travar a main thread por muito tempo.

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
         protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
             int count = urls.length;
             long totalSize = 0;
             for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                 totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
                 publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
                 // Escape early if cancel() is called
                 if (isCancelled()) break;
             }
             return totalSize;
         }

         protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
             setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
         }

         protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
             showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
         }
     }
```

Para executar a thread.

```
new DownloadFilesTask().execute(url1, url2, url3);
```

Comment: Com certeza é uma boa prática usar a AsyncTask, mas, conforme a pergunta, o problema não é ANR.

Comment: Não é ANR se a resposta for rapido o suficente, agora coloca o acesso a uma rede instavel, é sem duvida que dara um ANR. o ANR se tornara o problema principal, além disso usar threads para acesso a dados por redes não é apenas uma boa pratica , mas sim fundamental para o funcionamento do aplicativo, Resumindo usar Thread neste problema é primeira soluçao que deve-se fazer.

Comment: Boa explicação, @DuannistonCardosoCabral. Vou seguir seu raciocínio e ver no que dá. Em breve posto um feedback. Obrigado.